# How to add menu links to a node created within a test?

Tags: 8, testing

I want to create a test where a few nodes are created, and on those nodes are menu links.

The most I have found so far is:

```
    $options = array(
      'menu_name' => 'menu_test',
      'bundle' => 'menu_link_content',
      'link' => [['uri' => 'internal:/']],
    );
    $link = MenuLinkContent::create($options);
    $link->save();
```

How do I tie it and the node together? Just provide the node uri in the 'link' property? Would that just be `internal:node/(nid)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have just to provide an uri that identifies the node, for example `entity:node/1`

Use

```
'link' => ['uri' => 'entity:node/' . $nid],
```